# Prove $f(x) = x/(1+|x|)$ is a diffeomorphism.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, solution-verification, diffeomorphism

Let $|{}\cdot{}|$ be the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f(x) = x/(1+|x|)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Prove $f$ is a $C^{1}$ diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^n - \{0\}$.

Here is my sketch of proof:

1. $f$ is bijective:

Let $x_1$, $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

\begin{align}
f(x_1) &= f(x_2) \\
\frac{x_1}{1+|x_1|} &= \frac{x_2}{1+|x_2|} \\
x_1\cdot\frac{1+|x_2|}{1+|x_1|} &= x_2
\end{align}

So $x_1$ and $x_2$ are colinear, and $x_1 = 0 \implies x_2 = 0$. Let $x_1$, $x_2 \neq 0$. Consider $g: \mathbb{R}^{+}_{0} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(u) = 1/(1+u)$. Clearly $g$ is injective, and $|x_1|$, $|x_2| \in \mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}$, then:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+|x_1|} &= \frac{1}{1+|x_2|} \iff  |x_1| = |x_2| \\
\frac{x_2}{1+|x_1|} &= \frac{x_2}{1+|x_2|} \\
\frac{x_2}{1+|x_1|} &= \frac{x_1(1+|x_2|)}{(1+|x_1|)(1+|x_2|)}\\
x_1 &= x_2
\end{align}
Then, $f$ is injective.

Let $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}-{0}$:

\begin{align}
y &= \frac{x}{1+|x|}\\
(1+|x|)y &= x \tag 1
\end{align}

Applying the norm on (1), we have:
\begin{align}
|(1+|x|)y| &= |x|\\
|y|+|x||y| &= |x|\\
\frac{|y|}{1-|y|} &= |x| \tag 2
\end{align}

Replacing (2) in (1):
$x = \frac{y}{1-|y|}$
Then $f$ is surjective.
Therefore, $f$ is bijective.

2. $f$ is $C^{1}$:

\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{x}{1+|x|} \\ &= \frac{(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)}{1+|x|} \\ &= \left(\frac{x_1}{1+|x|}, \ldots, \frac{x_n}{1+|x|}\right)\\
\end{align}
Then,
$f_i(x) = \dfrac{x_i}{1+|x|}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$  and  $\displaystyle\frac{\partial{f_i(x)}}{\partial{x_j}} = \frac{1}{1+|x|}$ if $i=j$

$\displaystyle\frac{\partial{f_i(x)}}{\partial{x_j}} = 0$ if $i \neq j$

Then, all partial derivatives are continuous, so we conclude $f$ is $C^{1}$.

3. Diffeomorphism

Clearly $Jf(x) = \frac{1}{1+|x|} I_n$. Then, $\det(Jf(x)) = \left(\frac{1}{1+|x|}\right)^n \neq 0$. By the inverse function theorem, we conclude $f^{-1}$ is $C^{1}$. Therefore $f$ is a diffeomorphism.

Is my proof correct? I suspect the injective part is wrong or not well-supported. Finally, I don’t see why it is necessary to work on $\mathbb{R}-{0}$, it makes sense if it would be $\mathbb{R}^{n}-\{x\}$ such that $|x|=1$.

Comment: the inverse function theorem is a local result, and thus cannot prove that $f$ is a diffeomorphism

Comment: @Andrew It can if you show separately that $f$ is a bijection.